# Convert a ranked vector to matrix to show a pattern

Tags: r, matrix

I have a vector (some ranked observations) and I would like to place them in a matrix. [image: Matrix]

I basically want the highest number (rank) in upper right and the lowest in lower left regions. How can I do it in R?

Comment: Can you show the input vector

Comment: and example of output. Furthermore, you should show us for have you already tried.

Comment: It's a basic vector like  `a<-1:35`. For example,  names of  35 students ordered by score in mathematics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
m1 <- matrix(NA, 7,5)
m1[] <- rank(col(m1)-row(m1), ties.method='first')
m1
#    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]   21   26   30   33   35
#[2,]   16   22   27   31   34
#[3,]   11   17   23   28   32
#[4,]    7   12   18   24   29
#[5,]    4    8   13   19   25
#[6,]    2    5    9   14   20
#[7,]    1    3    6   10   15
```

Comment: Great :) Thank you so much.